# Database Cursor and error with columns

Tags: android, database, cursor

This is part of my database. I followed the position of the columns but there's still an error.

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_NOTE = "create table " + NOTE_TABLE + " ( "
        + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_MESSAGE + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_THOUGHTS + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_DATE + ");";


private Note cursorToNote(Cursor cursor){

//this part is underlined in red(error)

Note newNote = new Note (cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),
                        Note.Category.valueOf(cursor.getString(4)), cursor.getLong(0), cursor.getLong(5));
                return newNote;
            }
```

Note.java

```
public Note (String title, String message, Category category, long noteId, long dateCreatedMilli){
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
        this.thoughts = thoughts;
        this.category = category;
        this.noteId = noteId;
        this.dateCreatedMilli = dateCreatedMilli;
    }
```

Comment: What is your error? Also `COLUMN_DATE` type is missing.

Comment: Error:(112, 24) error: no suitable constructor found for Note(String,String,String,Category,long,long)
constructor Note.Note(String,String,Category) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Note.Note(String,String,Category,long,long) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length) +Misagh

Comment: missing from where +Misagh

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `thoughts` in constructor input parameters. Change it to this:

```
public Note (String title, String message, String thoughts, Category category, long noteId, long dateCreatedMilli){
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
        this.thoughts = thoughts;
        this.category = category;
        this.noteId = noteId;
        this.dateCreatedMilli = dateCreatedMilli;
    }
```

Comment: Oh yes ! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Third parameter of `Note()` constructor is type of `Category`, but you passed it a `String` (returned by `cursor.getString(3)` method)

Comment: isn't my third parameter COLUMN_THOUGHTS?

Comment: Yes, in your table. But no in your constructor. I think you made a mistake in your constructor. add "thoughts" to your constructor in third place.